# What exactly does this Azure error mean?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I have a PowerShell script that deploys an ARM template to Azure, but I have encountered an error that I can't quite seem to wrap my head around. When running in PowerShell, itself, I get the following error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 7:46:01 AM - Error:
>   Code=CannotUpdatePlan; Message=Resource plan can not be changed.

The error description doesn't seem all that complicated, but I'm not sure why this is the case in the first place. I don't have any locks on the Resource Group, resources, or subscription so it should theoretically be able to work properly, right?

Upon testing in VSTS, I got the error mentioned above *along with* the following error message preceding it:

> Selected subscription is in 'Disabled' state.

I'm not sure if that has to do with the other, but I know the subscription is active as I can deploy resources to it, manually. Also, it clearly says "Active" when viewing the subscription from the portal.

Comment: Is the subscription `Enabled` when viewing it with the Azure PS cmdlets?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes. Using Get-AzureRMSubscription, the State says "Enabled"

Comment: What specific ARM operation is causing this error? You can use https://resources.azure.com/ and look under providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments for the relevant resource group.

Comment: @LillaTheHun Do you try deploy this template on your local Power Shell. If it works, you had better share your VSTS configuration and your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could check as the following steps.

1.Ensure your subscription is enabled. For test, you could create a web app. If your subscription is really disabled, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-become-disable) re-active your subscription.

2.You had better check your subscription connection. Please ensure subscription is right. When you verify connection, it should show `Verified`.

[image]

Note: I use the agent `Hosted VS2017` and use Azure PowerShell script to deploy template.

Comment: If it does not work, I suggest you could create a new connection and test again.